# Elastic APM does not showing the Spans for NestJS application

Tags: node.js, nestjs, elk, apm, elastic-apm

```
import { Microservices } from '../configurations/constants';
import elasticApmNode from 'elastic-apm-node';

export const APM_SERVICE = 'APM_SERVICE';

// start APM function
export const startAPM = (service: Microservices) => {
  return elasticApmNode.start({
    serviceName: `backend_${service}`,
    secretToken: process.env.ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN || '',
    serverUrl: process.env.ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:8200',
    environment: process.env.ENV
  });
};
```

**main.ts**

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { GlobalErrorFilter } from './utils/error-capture';
import { startAPM } from '@app/shared/apm/apm-provider';
import { Microservices } from '@app/shared/configurations/constants';
import { sleep } from '@app/shared/utils/file-utils';
import { Logger } from '@app/shared/utils/logs';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

export const APM = startAPM(Microservices.apiThreatDetect);

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
// rest of the bootstrap
```

**controller.ts**

```
// new endpoint just for test elastic apm
  @Post('/test-elastic-apm')
  async testElasticApm() {
    const transaction = APM.startTransaction('Test Elastic APM', 'API Request');
    const span = transaction.startSpan('Test Elastic APM');
    // wait 2 seconds
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    span.end();
    transaction.end();
    return 'Test Elastic APM';
  }
```

I'm using `elasitc-apm-node` version `4.4.1` and it does not recognize any spans or the transaction(cannot see any logs in the console) in Elastic APM. Only the request has identified.

[image]

My node version is `v20.9.0`. Does anyone come across this issue or know how to resolve it?. It's perfectly working for my other nestJS micro services.